# PyCharm resolves call hierarchy infinitely

Tags: python, function, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I want to see the call hierarchy of a method. We can see that using `ctrl + alt + H` shortcut.

There are two modes to see the call hierarchy:

1. Caller Mode (*Resolves **calling** functions hierarchy*)
2. Calee Mode (*Resolves **called** functions hierarchy*)

I want to see the hierarchy in **Calee** mode and I want to configure such that **PyCharm should not infinitely resolve the hierarchy of recursive calls**. Instead, it should resolve the whole recursive hierarchy only once.

Highly appreciated if someone can help out with this.

Example:

```
def recur_fibo(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return recur_fibo(n - 1) + recur_fibo(n - 2)


nterms = 10

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <= 0:
    print("Plese enter a positive integer")
else:
    print("Fibonacci sequence:")
    for i in range(nterms):
        print(recur_fibo(i))
```

When you try to see call hierarchy for the above snippet in the **Calee** mode, and expand all, you see an infinitely expanding hierarchy like below:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a minimal code example that we can use to test it in our environment?

Comment: @SergeyK. Edited my question by adding an example

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a bug. Thanks for the code snippet!
I filed a ticket to our issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47824, please vote for it and feel free to comment.